# Prove the following statement for differentiability at $x_0$

Tags: real-analysis

"The function f is differentiable at $x_0$ if and only if $f_-'(x_0)$ and $f'_+(x_0) $ exist and equal."

The forward argument is rather easy but the backward argument, if we say $f_-'(x_0)$ and $f'_+(x_0) $ exist and equal, can we therefore deduce that $f_-'(x_0) = f'_+(x_0) =f'(x_0)$? and hence it is differentiable at $x_0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(h)=\frac {f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)} {h}$. Then the existence of $\lim_{h \to 0} g(h)$ is equivalent the fact that $\lim_{h \to 0+} g(h)$ and $\lim_{h \to 0-} g(h)$ both exist and the two limits are equal.  This should be obvious from definition of limits.